# Greater than last login time from db

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Okay, So I am wanting to get the new rows in a database since the last time the user had logged in.

The last login time is logged every time a user is logged in. It's stored in the database as a `datetime`.

The created date for the discussion is stored in the database as a `datetime`.

I need to take the `last login` time and compare it to the `created` time of the discussion. And return all the discussions that have been added since the last login of the logged in user.

In my model I tried doing this, but I got an error saying that I had an error in my sql.

`$time` is the last login time derived from the controller.

```
public function get_new($time)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('discussions', 'created <='.$time);

    return $query->result();
}
```

My controller has this code for calling the model.

```
$info = $this->aauth->get_user();

$time = $info->last_login;

$data['discussions'] = $this->discuss->get_new($time);
```

How can I get all new discussions that have been added since the last time the user logged in?

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter? If yes, you should add it to your tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your controller to this:

```
public function get_new($time)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('discussions', array('created <=' => $time));
    return $query->result();
}
```

I think you have to use `where()` instead of `get_where()` as per the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: `get_where` is the short hand version.... http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: @user3602774 ShortHand for what? Using `where()` you can have condition on your where like in your case `<=`

Comment: So I tried your code and Got this notice: `Message: Array to string conversion`

Comment: @user3602774 I had a syntax error in my answer. I just edited it, Have a try now

Comment: First off it needs to be `array('created <=' => $time));
` your missing the second `)`. Also I got the same notice with your edited answer.

Comment: I changed it from `where()` to `get_where()` and your code appeared to work.

Comment: @user3602774 Ahh just a tad late to suggest that lol. Anyways I updated my answer accordingly